# How angular to get updated model value inside onchange function declared inside directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a directive to show the value from db  to an input field based on the selection of a combo-box. Please see the below code for this.

html code:

```
<table class="table">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select show-threshold id="ins_id" name="ins_id" ng-model="pic.ins_id" ng-options="insurance.ins_id as insurance.Ins_name for insurance in ins" required class="form-control">
            <option value="">Choose PIC</option>
         </select>
         <div ng-if="pic_form.ins_id.$dirty && pic_form.ins_id.$invalid">
            <small class="error" ng-if="pic_form.ins_id.$error.required">This field is required</small>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="threshold" ng-model="pic.threshold" class="form-control" placeholder="Threshold value" required>
         <div ng-if="pic_form.threshold.$dirty && pic_form.threshold.$invalid">
            <small class="error" ng-if="pic_form.threshold.$error.required">Threshold is required</small>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

js code:

```
app.directive('showThreshold',function($http){
  return{
    restrict:'A',
    link:function(scope,element,attr)
    {

      element.on("change",function(){
        $http.get(site_url+"finance/getThreshold",{params:{ins_code:scope.pic.ins_id}}).success(function(data){
            scope.pic.threshold=data.threshold;
        });
      });

    }
  }
});
```

Inside the change() function I'm getting the previous model value when changing the selection box. How can I get the updated model value inside change function?

Actually I need the updated value of **scope.pic.ins_id**, but it's getting previously selected value.
Any help Appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your code not doing?

Comment: @deostroll, I'm not getting the updated model value of a selection field inside change function on the directive.

Comment: You don't seem to be updating `scope.pic.ins_id` correctly...perhaps review the code you've written for the success callback in your directive $http call...

Comment: @deostroll  pic.ins_id is the selection box model name, so it will be updated automatically when selection changes.

Comment: `pic.ins_id` should be set in the directive somewhere so that your select option changes likewise; the way you expect...so rather that `scope.pic.threshold = data.threshold`, you should proabaly be doing `scope.pic = data;`...assuming here that `data` is of that same schema of `scope.pic`